# Unable to access docker container web page in spite of port mapping on a MacOS Big Sur

Tags: spring, docker, docker-compose

I am using the following Docker compose file (which contains the port mappings):

```
version: '2'

services:
  config-server:
    image: springcommunity/spring-petclinic-config-server
    container_name: config-server
    mem_limit: 512M
    ports:
     - 8888:8888

  discovery-server:
    image: springcommunity/spring-petclinic-discovery-server
    container_name: discovery-server
    mem_limit: 512M
    depends_on:
      - config-server
    entrypoint: ["./dockerize","-wait=tcp://config-server:8888","-timeout=60s","--","java", "-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions", "-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
    ports:
     - 8761:8761

  customers-service:
    image: springcommunity/spring-petclinic-customers-service
    container_name: customers-service
    mem_limit: 512M
    depends_on:
     - config-server
     - discovery-server
    entrypoint: ["./dockerize","-wait=tcp://discovery-server:8761","-timeout=60s","--","java", "-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions", "-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
    ports:
    - 8081:8081

  visits-service:
    image: springcommunity/spring-petclinic-visits-service
    container_name: visits-service
    mem_limit: 512M
    depends_on:
     - config-server
     - discovery-server
    entrypoint: ["./dockerize","-wait=tcp://discovery-server:8761","-timeout=60s","--","java", "-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions", "-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
    ports:
     - 8082:8082

  vets-service:
    image: springcommunity/spring-petclinic-vets-service
    container_name: vets-service
    mem_limit: 512M
    depends_on:
     - config-server
     - discovery-server
    entrypoint: ["./dockerize","-wait=tcp://discovery-server:8761","-timeout=60s","--","java", "-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions", "-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
    ports:
     - 8083:8083

  api-gateway:
    image: springcommunity/spring-petclinic-api-gateway
    container_name: api-gateway
    mem_limit: 512M
    depends_on:
     - config-server
     - discovery-server
    entrypoint: ["./dockerize","-wait=tcp://discovery-server:8761","-timeout=60s","--","java", "-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions", "-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
    ports:
     - 8080:8080

  tracing-server:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin
    container_name: tracing-server
    mem_limit: 512M
    environment:
    - JAVA_OPTS=-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
    ports:
     - 9411:9411

  admin-server:
    image: springcommunity/spring-petclinic-admin-server
    container_name: admin-server
    mem_limit: 512M
    depends_on:
     - config-server
     - discovery-server
    entrypoint: ["./dockerize","-wait=tcp://discovery-server:8761","-timeout=60s","--","java", "-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions", "-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
    ports:
     - 9090:9090

  ## Grafana / Prometheus

  grafana-server:
    build: ./docker/grafana
    container_name: grafana-server
    mem_limit: 256M
    ports:
    - 3000:3000

  prometheus-server:
    build: ./docker/prometheus
    container_name: prometheus-server
    mem_limit: 256M
    ports:
    - 9091:9090
```

After doing a `docker-compose up`, I am able to see my services come up and also confirmed that the containers have been successfully created:

```
# docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                               COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                    PORTS                              NAMES
5e48351a3362   openzipkin/zipkin                                   "start-zipkin"           39 minutes ago   Up 38 minutes (healthy)   9410/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9411->9411/tcp   tracing-server
b6cc5aafb8f7   springcommunity/spring-petclinic-api-gateway        "./dockerize -wait=t…"   2 hours ago      Up 38 minutes             0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 8081/tcp   api-gateway
b104fc8da00e   springcommunity/spring-petclinic-admin-server       "./dockerize -wait=t…"   2 hours ago      Up 38 minutes             0.0.0.0:9090->9090/tcp             admin-server
7e9650ae3149   springcommunity/spring-petclinic-discovery-server   "./dockerize -wait=t…"   2 hours ago      Up 38 minutes             0.0.0.0:8761->8761/tcp             discovery-server
060afbce8965   springcommunity/spring-petclinic-config-server      "java -XX:+UnlockExp…"   2 hours ago      Up 38 minutes             0.0.0.0:8888->8888/tcp             config-server
d3d03a295b2f   spring-petclinic-microservices_prometheus-server    "/bin/prometheus --c…"   2 hours ago      Up 38 minutes             0.0.0.0:9091->9090/tcp             prometheus-server
e169b799a4ba   spring-petclinic-microservices_grafana-server       "/run.sh"                2 hours ago      Up 38 minutes             0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp             grafana-server
```

However, I still can't seem to hit the following 2 endpoints via my browser or via curl:

```
# curl http://localhost:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused

# curl http://localhost:9411
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9411: Connection refused
```

Also, the following is the version of `docker` that I'm using:

```
# docker version
Client:
 Cloud integration: 1.0.17
 Version:           20.10.8
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.16.6
 Git commit:        3967b7d
 Built:             Fri Jul 30 19:55:20 2021
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.12
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.10
  Git commit:       48a66213fe
  Built:            Mon Jun 22 15:49:35 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Also, here is the output of `dscacheutil`:

```
# dscacheutil -q host -a name localhost
name: localhost
ipv6_address: ::1
ipv6_address: fe80:1::1

name: localhost
ip_address: 127.0.0.1
```

Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Cheers!

Comment: are you sure that the spring containers are listening to those ports? I mean, `8761` is not the default port of spring, you might be just missing some port check (you might want to consider adding to `environment:` the env var `- server.port:8080` just to be sure)

Comment: Yeah this is based on the the following Spring git repo: https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-petclinic-microservices

Comment: every container has its own ip address (unless explicitely used static ip). So in order to connect to a container you have to first identify on which ip it is running and then use it to access your container. Else you can modify your compose file to add a static ip for the container to use

Comment: @wave - Apparently, on a Mac, you cannot access container IPs directly. You need to use localhost with port forwarding. See: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2670#issuecomment-371249949

Comment: ah i see, i was not aware of any mac specific issue. What i said was applies in general when you spawn containers they have their own IPs so you can not directly  access using localhost. If your problem is not yet resolved and its only for your local setup then you can use the static IP option i guess.

Comment: @wave I tried using static IPs. While the containers and the services within them came up, I still couldn't access them on my host machine. 

# curl http://10.5.0.7:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.5.0.7 port 8080: Operation timed out

`docker-compose.yml`:
networks:
  vpcbr:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
     config:
       - subnet: 10.5.0.0/16
         gateway: 10.5.0.1
api-gateway:
    ports:
     - 8080:8080
    networks:
      vpcbr:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.7

Comment: have you created the network vpcbr ? before using it in your docker compose file you have to create this network on your machine. refer https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/

Comment: See my previous answer. I did.

Comment: Just to clarify, the network can be created either by using the `docker create network` command or by specifying the `network:` section in the docker-compose.yml` file. I did the latter.

Comment: Any ideas, anyone?